# replace in multiline - refer to content for replacement

Tags: regex, perl, reference, multiline

I need the following:

input:

```
NAME-LIST:
name1
<any text>
name_to_be_changed;

NAME-LIST:
name3
<any text>
name_to_be_changed;
```

output: replace "name_to_be_changed" by first name in the block

```
NAME-LIST:
name1
<any text>
name1;

NAME-LIST:
name3
<any text>
name3;
```

result:

I would prefer a perl one-liner :-)

Comment: [`(NAME-LIST:\v(.*?)\v.*?)name_to_be_changed`](http://regex101.com/r/dG7qH4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all thanks for your input...

unfortunately I could not make use of both of your suggested solutions, but I have found an own one:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/(NAME-LIST:\s+)(\w+)(.*?)\w+;/$1$2$3$2;/gs'
```

`\s+` = 1 or more white spaces (space, newline, tab,...)

`\w+` = 1 or more alphanumericals (like words or numbers

important is the `/gs`

`g` = global (do the replacements more than one time, otherwise only the first name will be replaced)

`s` = treat as single line

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a search expression similar to what Sam already posted:

```
(NAME-LIST:[\t ]*[\r\n]+)([^\r\n]+)([\r\n]+[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+)name_to_be_changed;
```

The replace string is `\1\2\3\2;` or `$1$2$3$2;`

Each pair of opening and closing round brackets specify a marking group. There are three such marking groups in the search expression.

`[\t ]*` makes it possible that there are trailing spaces or tabs after fixed string `NAME-LIST:` at end of first line of a block.

`[\r\n]+` matches 1 or more carriage returns or linefeeds. That is similar to `\v` as used by Sam but does not match other vertical whitespaces like formfeed.

`[^\r\n]+` matches 1 or more characters which are whether a carriage return nor a linefeed. That is like `.` if the matching behavior for a dot is defined as matching all characters except line terminators.

`[^\r\n]*` matches 0 or more characters which are whether a carriage return nor a linefeed. So `<any text>` can be also no text at all which means third line can be also a blank line.

The 3 strings found by the expressions in the marking groups are backreferenced by `\1`, `\2` and `\3` respectively `$1`, `$2` and `$3` whereby only the second one is backreferenced twice to copy the string from line 2 to line 4 and keep the other 3 lines unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -00 -pe 's/NAMELIST:\n(.*)\n.*\n\K.*/$1/' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-00`: Paragraph mode
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.